# Как открыть ссылку при нажатие на кноку js в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript

Как открыть ссылку при нажатие на кноку js в новой вкладке.
Кнопка js полностью создана на js.Нужно чтобы открывалась ссылка a;

```
    var a=https://vk.com/id89413828;

btn6=document.createElement( 'BUTTON'); // создание кнопки

btn6.id='cmd6'; // её id 

btn6.textContent ='открыть новую ссылку '; // её текст

document.body.appendChild(btn6); // нужно чтобы добавилось 

btn6.onclick=function(){ // функция при клике на неё 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open();`

```js
var a = 'https://vk.com/id89413828'; //ссылка должна быть в ковычках, так как это строка

var btn6 = document.createElement('button'); // создание кнопки

btn6.id = 'cmd6'; // её id 

btn6.textContent = 'открыть новую ссылку '; // её текст

document.body.appendChild(btn6); // нужно чтобы добавилось 

btn6.onclick = function() { // функция при клике на неё 
  window.open(a);

}
```

**Кстати здесь не будет работать**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
btn6=document.createElement( 'BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
btn6.id='cmd6'; // её id 
btn6.textContent ='открыть новую ссылку '; // её текст
document.body.appendChild(btn6); // нужно чтобы добавилось 
btn6.onclick=function(){ // функция при клике на неё 
    window.open(a, '_blank').focus();
}
```